# How do I resolve a keybinding conflict with coc for vim?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, vimrc, tab-completion, vim-plugins

Just as a preface, I'm not a programmer, but I've written a bit of shell to automate things.

This is on MacOS Mojave, but it shouldn't make too big of a difference since neovim's configs should carry over.

I noticed that when I try to use coc's autocomplete feature, pressing enter just returns to next line rather than selecting an autocompletion. I suspected it's either related to vimwiki or markdown.
I looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298196/track-down-double-keybindings-conflicting-keys) to try to find the conflicting keybinding and I got this on the output of `:verbose imap <cr>` after trying to autocomplete:

```
i  <CR>        &@<C-]><Esc>:VimwikiReturn 1 5<CR><SNR>38_AutoPairsReturn
        Last set from ~/.config/nvim/plugged/auto-pairs/plugin/auto-pairs.vim line 662
i  <CR>        * pumvisible() ? "\<C-Y>" : "\<CR>"
        Last set from ~/.config/nvim/init.vim line 225
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

So I looked at `auto-pairs.vim` and I found this:

```
execute 'inoremap <script> <buffer> <silent> <CR> .old_cr.'<SID>AutoPairsReturn'
```

It seems to me like it's taking preference over the remap in `init.vim`:

```
inoremap <expr><cr> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<CR>"
```

I tried to find out where this `pumvisible()` function was located, but I couldn't find its definition. I figured I could stop the binding within auto-pairs by doing something with that.
I then tried changing the remap in `init.vim`. It didn't really do anything, I changed `<cr>` to `<Space>` and `<Right>` but that had a domino effect of making my arrow keys act like enter in all circumstances.

How can I correct this conflict?
If I have to edit the plugin files (I'm using vim-plug) then, how can I do it cleanly (so that it doesn't break on an update)?

Thank you. If necessary I can provide the full `init.vim` or my entire neovim config on github.

Answer (score 1):

The tab key mapping in vimwiki was conflicting with my coc.nvim autocomplete too, add this in your init.vim

```
au filetype vimwiki silent! iunmap <buffer> <Tab>
```

Comment: I been looking for this solution for literally years. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i Changed the  mapping for the COC setting

> inoremap <silent> <expr> <C-End> pumvisible() ? coc#_select_confirm()
> : "<C-g>u<CR><c-r>=coc#on_enter()<CR>"

now i select by pressing ctrl + end